# EF-core with PostgreSQL migration error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

In my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Host=localhost;Username={{postgres}};Password={{postgres}};Database={{asp_trial_api}};Port=5432;Pooling=true;"
    }
},
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

And in my startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddDbContext<WebAPIDataContext>(options => {
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
            });

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }
```

My `dotnet ef migrations add initial`was successful however `dotnet ef database update`gives me following error:

```
28P01: password authentication failed for user "{{postgres}}"
```

The username and password I provided in my connection string is however correct. I have already created a blank database with the name **asp_trial_api** in my PostgresSQL.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems like have some missing attributes in the connection string such as `User ID` and `Server`. Try the following CS

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password={{pass}};Server=localhost;Port=1234;Database={{database}};Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
},
```

I have a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/kjanshair/docker-aspnetcore-db) for a working example of an ASP.NET Core application with a Postgres database.

Comment: This looks promising but it gave me `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` error. Possible reasons? I deleted the database asp_trial_api and created a new one api_trial and refreshed everything.

Comment: Is the server port and user name are correctly configured in the connection string? I also had the same problem but came to know that the `User ID` was in correct (in my case). Can you double check it?

Comment: Also replace the connection string that I just provided with your one, modify the values and see whether it works!

Comment: Yes I actually I copied your string and forgot to update port number. Now I set to my port number but then it threw me `28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Do you use any password when logging in to your PostgreSQL server?

Comment: Yes, that password is also postgres. I basically followed http://kerryritter.com/getting-started-with-postgresql-ef7-mvc6/ this blogpost where they say connection string is a bit different for postgres.

Comment: That sounds interesting, the problem occurs when you don't use a password. Probably you should change your PostgreSQL password and make sure that PostgreSQL server is opened logged in! If this still not works. We should use IM as Stackoverflow is suggesting to avoid extended discussions in comments. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136608/discussion-between-nitish-and-janshair-khan).

Comment: Thank you, i experienced this issue and the reason is that "User ID=myUsername" was missing from my connection string